# Will Adding an Identity Column to a T-SQL Table Break Anything

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I've got a legacy database that has several keyless tables. On one, I'd really just like to throw an Identity column on it so I can use it with Entity Framework. Now, I know I can do this:

```
alter table MyTable
add Id int identity(1,1)
```

But as this is an old and hoary beast, I want to make sure it's not going to break anything. I can't imagine how it would break any procs or existing data access (some of which is still in VB 6!) but "cant' imagine" isn't quite the same as "absolutely sure."

I was hoping some experts on databases could give me some guidance here.

Comment: Does anything use `Select * from ...` and then refer to the columns by their index as opposed to their name?

Comment: If you somewhere use `*` instead of specifying the column namnes you might end up in trouble depending on how the client is coded.

Comment: I would say a Select * and then referring to the columns by index is certainly possible, somewhere. However, the identity gets added as the last column on the table, so I'm not thinking this would affect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code has any "Select *" in it, it could break something.

example:

You create a #temp table with 3 columns.

Your table in question has 3 columns.

You use "select * from TheTable" to populate the #temp table.

Now you add a 4th column to the table.

Your code will now try to jam 4 columns into a 3 column #temp table.

Having an IDENTITY column that is not the PrimaryKey could be another snap-fu.

Comment: I cannot imagine any situation in which have the additional id column as a not-PK would cause a problem. In facts, odds are good there is already a PK that can simply continue to be used as the PK.

Comment: It may not cause an issue.  However, there is this little voice in my head going "remember that time you created a edmx file on a table where the IDENTITY was not the PK"...and EF didn't like that.  (This was early EF, I use "mappings" now).......so it is just a hunch, nothing concrete that I have to describe.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to learn why this could possibly cause a problem is why I commented (not big on harshness in general). Buggy software can be very touchy indeed. So your answer is mostly, should not be an inherent problem, but ...